# Weird behaviour at a PDF Document opened with Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, pdf, checkbox

i´ve got a strange problem. I have a PDF document with html checkboxes. When i click in one checkbox, the checkbox is bordered and checked. When i want to check the next checkbox, the first checkbox will unchecked. The focus is on the first checkbox. I need to click in the upper or lower area at the document to check/uncheck other checkboxes.

I hope you know what i mean, don´t know how to explain..

Comment: What is a "PDF document with HTML checkboxes"?

Comment: A normal PDF File which contains Checkboxes

Comment: What is your actual question, what do you want to know?